# Data request: guidance to find football betting data

Tags: econometrics, data-request

Can someone please guide me to find data which fulfills following requests:

- It should be from one of the major leagues: Premier League, Bundesliga, La liga or Serie A.
- From a given betting company, I need odds for a home win, draw, away win for all games in an entire season
- It doesn't matter for which season but I would prefer for a recent season.

Comment: Seems more relevant for OpenData.SE